# python: zipping csv buffers

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, csv, zip

I want to zip some csv buffers into a new zip buffer as follows (python 2.7):

```
files = []

csv_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer)
writer.writerow(["some", "csv", "data"])

csv_buffer.seek(0)

files.append(csv_buffer)

zipped_file = io.BytesIO()

with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zipper:
    for i, csv_file in enumerate(files):
        csv_file.seek(0)
        zipper.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), csv_file.read())

zipped_file.seek(0)
```

Then I dispatch the resulting buffer through a Django view to download. However if I open the zip, I find a file (0.csv), but it is not correctly encoded. I would like to have it encoded as UTF-8.

I tried also as follows:

```
zipper.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), csv_file.read().encode("utf-8"))
```

but that made no difference. Also changing

```
zipped_file = io.BytesIO()
```

to

```
zipped_file = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Didn't help.
Any ideas about what went wrong would be much appreciated!

**EDIT: My Solution**

Despite the otherwise helpful and interesting answers hereunder I solved the problem by changing

```
    zipper.writestr("{}.csv".format(i), csv_file.read())
```

to

```
     zipper.writestr(zipfile.Zipinfo("foo.csv"), csv_file.read())
```

Dont know why, but that made it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems you are not encoding your CSV properly.

Take a look at this note in the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) docs (Python 2.7):

> **Note** This version of the `csv` module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

This is the example they are referring to:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Just use `UnicodeWriter` instead of `csv.writer` (a drop-in replacement):

```
writer = UnicodeWriter(csv_buffer)
```

instead of:

```
writer = csv.writer(csv_buffer)
```

Or, if you can, switch to Python 3 which handles Unicode much better than Python 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still no success with UnicodeWriter. The CSV buffer is OK now, but still if I try to zip it, it gets somehow corrupted. If I hex dump the unzipped CSV, I get 00000000: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       .............

Comment: If I try the same, but write to files instead of buffers, all works fine. This might be a workaround, but I still would like to use buffers instead of files on disk. What could be the problem here??

Comment: I've just tried saving your `zipped_file` to a file on disk (with `f.write(zipped_file.getvalue())`), and that file is a perfectly good zip file, with a perfectly good CSV inside (with UTF-8 encoded text). That tells me the problem is somewhere in the part of the app you omitted in the question - are you sure Django reads and serves this buffer properly?

Comment: Thanks randomir for this clue! I tried the same (write to disk instead of serving as download), and that worked! So as you suggested, the problem should be with Django not serving the buffer properly. Thanks again, and I accepted your answer.